# Phonegap Notification Prompt Callback Issue

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build

I have a PhoneGap app that takes a user prompt value and uploads that parameter to my company server.

A process is kicked off that creates a chart and returns it to the app. I'm having trouble setting up a callback function that kicks off the process. As it stands, when I build the app with this code, I just get a grey screen when I open the app. If I take the onPrompt callback out, the app loads, but I'm not able to pass the user prompt to the taskParams.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
window.navigator.notification.prompt(
    new String(), // message
    function(answer) {
        if (answer.buttonIndex === 1) {
            // Ok
            locationStr = answer.input1;
            answer.executeSql("INSERT INTO cat (Name) VALUES (?)", [locationStr]);
        } else {
            // Exit
        }
    }
    onPrompt, // callback
    "Enter Location Name", //title
    ["Ok", "Exit"], // button titles
    new String() // defaultText
);

var taskParams = {
    "Latitude": lat,
    "Longitude": lon,
    "Location": locationStr
};

function onPrompt() {
    domAttr.set(dom.byId("chartLink"), "innerHTML", "Generating Chart...");
    window.gp_chart.execute(taskParams, gpChartResultAvailable, gpChartFailure);
}
```

Comment: I assume there's a `,` before `onPrompt` in your actual code? Edit: the docs say `prompt()` has five parameters: `message, promptCallback, [title], [buttonLabels], [defaultText]` Your are trying to pass two functions, an anonymous one and `onPrompt`.

Comment: Have you tried popping open the console in inspection mode to see if an error message is thrown?  It would probably tell you that you're missing the comma that Chris G mentioned

Comment: I changed the parameters to: 'Enter a Location Name',  // message
    onPrompt,                  // callback to invoke
    'Location',            // title
    ['Ok','Exit'],           // buttonLabels
    new String()  // Default text           but I'm still getting a grey screen

Comment: I'm opening it in Weinre debugger and getting no messages

Comment: OK. I changed it back to ,
    onPrompt, // callback
            "Enter Location Name", //title
            ["Ok", "Exit"], // button titles
            new String() // defaultText                                                              with the comma at the beginning. No more grey screen, but I'm unable to click the DOM link that kicks off the prompt

Comment: var link = domConstruct.create("a",{
                "class": "action", 
                "id": "chartLink",
                "innerHTML": "Three Week Chart", //text that appears in the popup for the link 
                "href": "javascript: void(0);"
              }, query(".actionList", map.infoWindow.domNode)[0]);
          
    on(link, "click", function()
    { 
     window.navigator.notification.prompt

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing the prompt's callback with the database query's success callback.

Here they are, separated:

```
// database setup
var db = window.openDatabase(name, version, displayName, estimatedSize);

window.navigator.notification.prompt(
  "Enter Location Name: ", // message
  handleLocationPrompt, // callback
  "Add location", //title
  ["Ok", "Exit"] // button titles
);

// handle user's dialog action
function handleLocationPrompt(results) {
  if (results.buttonIndex === 1) {
    // Ok
    addLocationToDB(results.input1);
  }
}

function addLocationToDB(locationStr) {
  if (!locationStr) return; // don't add empty string
  // run query, pass success callback function as 3rd parameter
  db.transaction(function(tx) {
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO cat (Name) VALUES (?)", [locationStr], querySuccess);
  });
}

var taskParams = {
  "Latitude": lat,
  "Longitude": lon,
  "Location": locationStr
};

// handle successful db insertion
function querySuccess() {
  domAttr.set(dom.byId("chartLink"), "innerHTML", "Generating Chart...");
  window.gp_chart.execute(taskParams, gpChartResultAvailable, gpChartFailure);
}
```

Edit: Updated code to include db code unrelated to question

Comment: So I need to set up db as a variable, correct? I tried this before, but it didn't work. I took the executeSQL line from an example I found online. Which Cordova plugin do I need? Right now I have WebSQL in my config file.

Comment: You need to establish a database connection and store it in `db`. Then you need to call `db.transaction()`, and call `executeSql` on the callback's param. The `db.executeSql` line in my example will **not** work as-is, but DB operations, that's a separate question. See: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/storage/storage.html#websql

Comment: I got this error: Error in Success callbackId: Notification784468272 : TypeError: db.executeSql is not a function.

Comment: After I defined var db = window.openDatabase('myDB', "", 'DB', 100000);

Comment: I answered that in my comment and linked you to the docs that show an example. In essence you need `db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(...); });`

Comment: OK. I tried this and the console printed: SQLTransaction
__proto__: —

Comment: function onPrompt(results) {
      if (results.buttonIndex === 1) {
     locationStr = results.input1;
     db.transaction(function (tx) {
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO cat (Name) VALUES (?)", [locationStr], function (tx, result) {
     console.log(result);
    }, function (error) {
     console.log(error);
    });
   });
      }
    }

Comment: @BillHambone I updated the code in my question to show how to do this. Again, the first line is example code; it obviously won't work as-is. Replace it with the line you have. Now stop it; this is a **separate question**.